# nothing is affecting viewport

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, properties

I opened my donut project that I had been working on, and all of my materials and properties had been gone and were not showing up on my donut in viewport, except they were all still in the properties window like I had left them, they just were not affecting the donut for some reason. It also said I was rendering in cycles, when clearly i was rendering in evee as you can see in the photo. So it seems that nothing I do that isnt directly in the viewport(like scaling, rotating, moving the donut or moving the camera) isnt affecting the model, but all the data from the properties and materials is still there. HELP!

[image]

Comment: maybe you should watch some basic tutorials about blender like here https://www.blender.org/support/tutorials/. they are free and really good for beginners.

Answer (score 1):

did you try out to press one of these buttons?

[image]

They change the way objects will be shown in the viewport.

Comment: YES! Thank you Chris, I am forever in your debt!

Comment: no problem. Glad i could help. Please press the checkmark left to my answer. Thank you.